# Equivalence of simple formulations of qubit entanglement

Tags: quantum-information, tensor-calculus, quantum-entanglement, probability

I'm reading some very elementary treatments of quantum computation and am unsure about the correspondence among "definitions" of qubit entanglement.

One definition states that (1) the bits of a two-qubit system are entangled if the state cannot be expressed as the (tensor) product of two one-qubit states. Another "definition" states that (2) a two-qubit system is entangled if "we cannot determine the state of each qubit separately" or if (3) "measuring one qubit determines the distribution of the other".

Perhaps my confusion is a simple matter of not fully understanding what the "independent" means and how it relates to the tensor product; but it's not clear to me how these statements are related. Does, for example (1) imply (2)? Are (2) and (3) equivalent?

Comment: Definition (1) is the standard definition I would say, it also applies to larger systems and parties. Comment (2) seems like a vague restatement of (1). I would say observation (3) *follows* from (1).

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian That makes sense. Is there also a fourth: (4) if two states are entangled, it is not possible to express one of them without referring to the state of the other?

Comment: You need to be careful with what you mean. You can describe a subsystem without the rest of the system via a partial trace. The best definition is (1) because is mathematically precise.

Comment: For completeness, you can describe the single qubit of the cat state $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$ as $|0\rangle +|1\rangle$ (modulo normalisations). This is to say that when you do that, you know nothing: 50/50 either possibility, up or down. All of this via the partial trace.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Yes, good point. I meant (4) serves as more of an "interpretation" (yes I know that's fraught) than a definition. "Partial trace" has always confused me. _Any_ help understanding it in this context would be appreciated (and make for a very robust answer).

Comment: Let me write all of this up!

Comment: A nice way to understand what the partial trace does is by studying the expectation value of some local operator. Say you have some lattice system for simplicity. Let's also say you want to measure $$\mathcal{O} \doteq I \otimes \cdots \otimes O \otimes \cdots \otimes I$$ that is, an operator only acting on some region of the lattice, e.g. the magnetisation in some section of a material. We know that if our system is in some state $\rho$, then $$\langle \mathcal{O}\rangle_\rho = \text{Tr} (\mathcal{O} \rho)$$.

Comment: Ah, but we can further simplify, because we know $\mathcal{O}$ is mostly the identity everywhere. If we call the region where $\mathcal{O}$ is not the identity $A$ and the rest $B$ and define a basis where these are distinct we have $$\langle \mathcal{O} \rangle_\rho = \sum_{i_A, j_B} \langle i_A, j_B | \mathcal{O} \rho |i_A, j_B\rangle$$ but $\mathcal{O}$ is the identity in $B$! We have
$$... = \sum_{...} \langle i_A| O( \langle j_B |\rho |j_B \rangle) |i_A \rangle$$

Comment: Now is only natural to define $$\rho_A =\sum_{j_B} \langle j_B | \rho | j_B\rangle$$ as the effective density matrix in region $A$ or, as everybody else calls it, the *reduced density matrix* in region $A$. So people suggestively write $$ \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle_\rho = \text{Tr}_A( O \rho_A) $$ where now you know how and why people defined $\text{Tr}_A( \text{something})$.